# How do I add a layer to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, depth

I have an array, like so:

```
var times = ["mon","tue"];
```

How would I make that into:

```
times = [["mon","tue"]];
```

Thanks

Comment: Wrap it in an array `times = [times]` ?

Comment: So it wa that simple? Thanks!

Comment: Everything in JavaScript composes. Arrays can contain any value from numbers to functions to other arrays. Try to learn, understand, and apply this composability and you will profit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this out for yourself in the console

```
const time = ['1', '2'];
```

```
const times = [time];
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way...

```js
var times = ["mon","tue"];

var newArr = [];

newArr.push(times);

console.log(newArr);
```